# Registering without e-mail adress!

Tags: user-registration

How I can make users register by name and password only without e-mail?
I searched a lot but all what I found for old wordpress version
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

WordPress registration process is based on the use of email. You can create your own registration page, and use fake random email just to fill the required email field, but you need to custom code registration process up to a point.

How will you reach your users, if you have no way to contact them?

Comment: "fake random email just to fill the required email field" How I can make that?! I don't want to reach my users :) anonymous

Comment: And what if they need to reset the password (or if they have lost the password), how they will be able to prove that they are how they say they are. There are reasons why all websites require an email. Anyway, this is not a simple change to make. If I was to work this for a client, I would need at least 2 days to implement, considering a number of changes and testing required to make sure nothing is broken.